# Is there a portable version of ungoogled-chromium for ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, chromium, browser, portable

I'd really like to use the "ungoogled-chromium"-browser alongside firefox- but as a portable version. This mean: All the necessary files are stored in one folder and/or subfolders, so that I can move the folder whereever I want and run it from this location without losing the browser cache, settings and so on ..
For example to switch between ubuntu computers.

If you take a look on the [download site](https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/), the linux download-file is already called "portable". But if I extract the file and run the browser, it creates folders in my user-directory for example in .config, .cache

I saw a post, where someone [helped a user with creating a script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051236/1188425), who wanted a portable version of chrome. Is something like this maybe also possible for this ungoogled-chromium..? Or another way? It would mean a lot to me :)

Thanks for any help or information anyway!

Comment: You already got an answer - I would like only to add that the word "portable" when describing an application usually means only that the application does not require installation; you just download it and run. It does not promise that you can move the application after use together with it's config or data files to a different computer. In the Windows world, I know of several "portable" applications that are storing config in Windows Registry like regular "installable" applications.

Comment: interesting ... thanks for the info!! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> AppImage aims to be an application deployment system for Linux with the following objectives: simplicity, binary compatibility, distro agnosticism, no installation, no root permission, being portable, and keeping the underlying operating system untouched.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppImage#:~:text=AppImage%20aims%20to%20be%20an,the%20underlying%20operating%20system%20untouched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppImage#:%7E:text=AppImage%20aims%20to%20be%20an,the%20underlying%20operating%20system%20untouched).

### Download here as an AppImage:

https://ungoogled-software.github.io/ungoogled-chromium-binaries/releases/appimage/64bit/

Download the latest version and run `chmod +x /PATH/TO/ungoogled-chromium_<version>.AppImage`, create a folder in the same directory as the AppImage named `ungoogled-chromium_<version>.AppImage.home` to store all the data in there instead of your home directory, then execute it.

https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/portable-mode.html

###### Enjoy :)

Comment: I feel sooo (!) stupid- I always though, why is there this AppImage-format, but it stores the cache and other file in the home directory anyway ...?! I never knew, that I have to create a extra folder for this ...! Maybe I had to research more ... anyway- you helped me a lot...!!!! This will help me massive with all other AppImage Files now! xD If carma exists, you get 1/4 of my total :P

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to download the semi-official build from the public Chromium sources.

For example, a process of some Chromium version `95.0.4638` files search and download (adjusted [steps](https://chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) originally written for version 44):

1. Look in [https://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/search/label/Stable updates](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/search/label/Stable%20updates) for the last time version `4638` was mentioned. There is a field which queries the general Google:

   [image]

   [image]

   Selected one of the above results and:

   [image]
2. Loop up that version history (specifically, `95.0.4638.69`) in the [Position Lookup](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/);

   [image]
3. In this case it returns a base position of `920003`. This is the commit of where the 95 release was branched, back in September 2021:

   [image]
4. Try searching in all required platforms (i.e. [Linux](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux/), [Linux x64](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/), [Windows](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/), [Windows x64](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/), [Mac](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/) etc.) on [continuous builds archive](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) - paste "920003" into the filter field at the top and wait for all the results to XHR in. If no results is shown, try incrementing or decrementing the value (i.e. `920004`, `920005` etc.).
5. Eventually, it showed `920005` at [Linux x64](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/920005/):

   [image]
6. Download the required file (e.g. [chrome-linux.zip](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F920005%2Fchrome-linux.zip?generation=1631232582939202&alt=media)).
7. Unzip and voilà:

   [image]

---

Why `95.0.4638.0` instead of `95.0.4638.69`? From the original [steps page](https://chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) mentioned above:

> As this build was made at 44 branch point, it does not have any commits merged in while in beta.

It's also worth to mention that `www.` for `googleapis.com` is mandatory.

---

For a broad example, to download the archive and run Chromium `95.0.4638.0-dev-x64`:

```bash
if [ ! -f './chrome-linux/chrome' ];
then
    wget -O './chrome-linux.zip' -- 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F920005%2Fchrome-linux.zip?generation=1631232582939202&alt=media';
    unzip './chrome-linux.zip';
fi

cd './chrome-linux';

declare tmpDirpath; # Just in case it's a local variable
tmpDirpath="$( mktemp; )";
readonly tmpDirpath;
printf -- $'Temporary User directory: \'%s\'\n' "$tmpDirpath";

'./chrome' --user-data-dir="$tmpDirpath";
```

As mentioned in the above quite broad "script", in order to have a more isolated or "portable" environment, try setting option [--user-data-dir](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/user_data_dir.md#overriding-the-user-data-directory) for the executable.